# Раскрыть смысл афоризма

Tags: общие-вопросы

Будьте любезны, помогите понять афоризм:

> Доказывать человеку необходимость знания — это все равно что убеждать
>   его в полезности зрения.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл прост: ***знания необходимы***, и это настолько очевидно, что не требует доказательств. Дополнительная аргументация: *доказывать это **излишне*** - как и в случае столь же очевидного утверждения, что *иметь зрение - полезно для человеа.*

Comment: Александр премного благодарен .